# CakePHP HABTM accessing associated table for display?

Tags: cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

For some reason i'm really having a hard time wrapping my head around HABTM associations. I learn best by watching someone do something and explaining why. Anyways, I have 2 tables I want associated, Drugs, and SideEffects. I've created the intermediate table drugs_side_effects(has no data right now). Does cake put the data in that automatically or do I need to do something? The 3.7.6.5 hasAndBelongsToMany (HABTM) from the book didn't specify.

I've set up the models correctly(I think) and am not sure how to proceed at this point. It seems pretty simple. I need to display side_effect from the SideEffects table in a Drug view. I think in the edit_french controller function i'll need something like

```
$side_effect = $this->Drug->SideEffect->read(
    array('SideEffect.id','SideEffect.side_effect'), $id);
$this->set('side_effect',$side_effect);
```

but I feel like that won't work as expected. Or maybe there's a more efficient way? Any advice or help is appreciated.

**Drug Model:**

```
  var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'SideEffect' => array(
      'className' => 'SideEffect',
      'joinTable' => 'drug_side_effects',
      'foreignKey' => 'drug_id',
      'associationForeignKey' => 'side_effect_id'
      )
  );
}
?>
```

**SideEffect Model:**

```
  var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
     'Drug' => array(
        'className' => 'Drug',
        'joinTable' => 'drug_side_effects',
        'foreignKey' => 'side_effect_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'drug_id'
     )
  );
}
?>
```

**Drugs Controller:**

```
<?php
class DrugsController extends AppController {
  var $name = 'Drugs';
  var $helpers = array('Html','Form','Paginator');
  var $paginate = array(
    //'contain' => array('SideEffect'),
    //'fields' => array('Drug.id', 'Drug.generic'),
    'fields' => array('Drug.id', 'Drug.generic','Drug.date_altered'),
    'limit' => 50,
    'order' => array(
        'Drug.generic' => 'asc'
      )
  );

  function index() {
    $data = $this->paginate('Drug');
    $alldrugs = $this->set('drugs', $this->Drug->find('all'));
    $this->set('drugs', $data);
    $this->set('alldrugs', $data);
    //$this->set('lessdrugs', $this->paginate());
    $this->set('title_for_layout','List of all current drugs');
  }

  function edit_french($id = null) {
    $this->Drug->id = $id;
    $drug = $this->Drug->read(
      array(
          'Drug.id','Drug.generic','Drug.ahl','Drug.aap','Drug.rid','Drug.oral','Drug.mw','Drug.clinical_recommendations'
      ),
      $id
    );
    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Translate clinical recommendations - ' . $drug['Drug']['generic']);
    $this->set('drug',$drug);

    if (empty($this->data)) {
       $this->data = $this->Drug->read();
    } else {
       if ($this->Drug->save($this->data)) {
         $this->Session->setFlash('The drug has been updated.');
         $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
       }
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pull the related data using [`ContainableBehavior`](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/containable-behavior). To do so, simply run a find on the Drug model and tell it to contain the associated SideEffect data.

```
$drug = $this->Drug->find('first', array(
  'conditions' => array(
    'Drug.id' => $id
  ),
  'contain' => array(
    'SideEffect'
  )
));
```

You can also set the contain before using `read()` if you prefer.

```
$this->Drug->contain(array('SideEffect'));
$drug = $this->Drug->read(null, $id);
```

Using Containable allows you to gather all associated data in a single `find()` request.

Comment: I will give that a try. Would I display it the same as the drug info in the view? ie $side_effect['SideEffect']['side_effect']?

Comment: Okay, I tried that, but I guess i'm not using the correct syntax to display the side effect in the view?

Comment: Debug `$drug` to see how it returns. Better yet, use debug kit (https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit). It should be `$drug['SideEffect'][0]['name']` and so on.